# JS basic hide/show div fails

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for coming up with questions this basic, but I'm kinda struck. I intended this code to list questions until test ends. Instead, right after switching the divs, it reverts back to question 1 for some unknown reason =\

Please kindly help and thanks forward!

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
       return;   
    }

    function divswitcher(d1,d2) {
      toggle_visibility(d1);
      toggle_visibility(d2);
      return;
    }
</script>

<div id="q1" style="display: block">
Q1 text
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1a1"/>Q1A1 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1a2"/>Q1A2 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1a3"/>Q1A3 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1a4"/>Q1A4 text</li>
</ul>
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q1','q2');" />Next</a>
</div>

<div id="q2" style="display: none">
Q2 text
<form>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2a1"/>Q2A1 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2a2"/>Q2A2 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2a3"/>Q2A3 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2a4"/>Q2A4 text</li>
</ul>
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q2','q3');" />Next</a>
</form>
</div>

<div id="q3" style="display: none">
Q3 text
<form>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q3a1"/>Q3A1 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q3a2"/>Q3A2 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q3a3"/>Q3A3 text</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q3a4"/>Q3A4 text</li>
</ul>
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q3','final');" />Next</a>
</form>
</div>

<div id="final" style="display: none">
Yay!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1/ replace <a>anchor with button tag

2/ Page reloads due to anchor tag and hence you are back to Q1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anchor with an empty href reloads the page, try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="divswitcher('q3','final');">Next</a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sHxGZ/)

or `return false` or `preventDefault` in your handler

Answer (score 0):

Replace your  tag (note the typo `/>`, you must only use the `/` char for closing the link) :

```
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q3','final');" />Next</a>
```

by

```
<a href="#" onclick="divswitcher('q3','final');">Next</a>
```

Comment: Thanks ) That helped. I really should be more attentive, though (

Answer (score 0):

Its due to **anchor** tag : when we click on NEXt - the page reloads and hence we are back to Q1

I suggest you to use **button** instead of **anchor** tag

**REPLACE**

```
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q1','q2');" />Next</a>
```

**WITH**

```
<button type="button" onclick="divswitcher('q1','q2');">NEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One error is you are closing your a tags twice and linking to a blank href="":

```
<a href="" onclick="divswitcher('q1','q2');" />Next</a>
```

change to

```
<a onclick="divswitcher('q1','q2');">Next</a>
```

That should fix it. If you want the nice pointer when you hover over the a tag, add this style:

```
a{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```